# On or In this matter?

Tags: in-on

"Decision Making? I believe I do okay in/on this matter."

Should I use 'on' or 'in'?

Comment: Use on, so it will become "I believe I do okay on this matter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Smokey Stover's answer over on the [Phrase Finder Discussion Forum](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/57/messages/969.html) (April 10, 2008) is correct:

> Could you explain [to] me the the difference ... [in] use [between] 'in this matter'
>   ... [and] 'on this matter'?

[Rodica]

> In general, either is correct, both meaning "in regard to this
>   matter." Often the preceding wording suggests a preference, as in,
>   e.g.,
>
> "I would like to have your opinion on this matter."
>
> But, on the other hand,
>
> "I'm not sure how to proceed in this matter."
>
> Sentences often begin, "In the matter of ...," and this is NOT
>   interchangeable
>   with "On the matter of...." (If you're in doubt you can say, "In
>   regard to....") I can't give you a rule to cover all cases. The
>   idiomatic use of prepositions is tricky even for native speakers.

[Smokey Stover] (reformatted)

I don't think that either variant here ("Decision Making? I believe I do okay in/on this matter.") is very idiomatic (and I'd certainly avoid 'on', which hints strongly at 'I can discuss *decision making* articulately'). I'd use either "Decision Making? I believe I do okay." in an informal register or "As regards decision making: I believe I am reasonably competent in this area." in a formal one.